# Intellij IDEA 2016.3 Ruby SDK and Gems not shown in Settings

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, configuration

I have new Intellij IDEA 2016.3 installed and just wanted to configure a Ruby SDK for my project. I have installed Ruby Plugin (editor support works as expected) but I cannot find a menu in Settings for "Ruby SDK and Gems" (as I know this from RubyMine that I had before). Shift+Ctrl+A does not deliver any other places for that. Have I overseen something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI for configuring the Ruby SDK is different between RubyMine and the IntelliJ IDEA Ruby plugin. To configure a Ruby SDK in IntelliJ IDEA, you need to go to the Project Structure dialog, select the SDKs page, press the + button and select the Ruby SDK type from the popup.